# DBeaver connection to Postgres server stuck on "Read Data from Container"

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, dbeaver

I am currently trying to view a postgres database. However, it is stuck on `"Read Data from Container"` for several hundred seconds. This all happened after I deleted a table and recreated it. Any ideas what this could be? At some points DBeaver will end up crashing. My fetch size is only 200.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I ran `htop` and it appeared the server switched over to swap. Increased RAM in virtualization and it now works again! Appears that me running a database backup through DBeaver may have caused this congestion as the server only had 10 gb of ram.